# Open local repository to others as a remote one

Tags: apache, ftp, repository, maven, share

Is there any simple way,which is provided by maven itself, to open my local repo as a remote one for other users?(How cool it would be;) )

Or should I install an ftp server or apache to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not straightforward.  What you are looking to do is to set up a [mirror of the repositories](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html) to be used by other users.  You will be better of setting up one of the [repository managers](http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) to do this.

Comment: Nop.Not useful. I think, I'll install apache for it. Thanks anyway.